# Perpendicular (orthogonal) vector proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

Show that two nonzero vectors $\vec{v_1}$,$\vec{v_2}$ ∈ $\mathbb{R_3}$ are orthogonal if and only if their direction angles satisfy
cos$α_1$ cos$α_2$ +cos$β_1$ cos$β_2$ +cos$γ_1$ cos$γ_2$ =0.

Note: I tried to turn all of the cos$[angle]_2$ to sin[angle] and then convert all of the cos[angle] terms to $v_x$/||$\vec{v}$|| and sin[angle] terms to $v_y$/||$\vec{v}$||, but that was where I got stuck.

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The vectors are orthogonal
if and only if
their dot product is zero.
The direction cosines
are just the vector
divided by its length.

Therefore,
the dot product of the vectors
is zero
if and only if
the dot product of the direction cosines
is zero.